# Multiple choice ListView: is it possible to select the row only when clicking the checkbox instead of the entire row?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox, multiple-choice

### Question

Like the subject says, I would like to mark the list view row as **checked** only when clicking the relative checkbox instaed of the entire row.

[image]

Is is possible?

### Code

ListView view in the main layout:

```
<ListView 
        android:id="@+id/lv_anprreading_reading_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cb_anprreading_select_all"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_blue"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_border_trasparent_bck" />
```

Adapter layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<it.helian.infrastructure.FE.ui.widget.CheckableLinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_plate_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="3dp" >

    <it.helian.infrastructure.FE.ui.widget.InertCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_white"
        android:focusable="false" />  
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_plate_plate" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:text="@string/dummy_vehicle_plate"
        android:textSize="@dimen/anprreading_reading_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_plate_country" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".15"
        android:text="@string/dummy_string"
        android:textSize="@dimen/anprreading_reading_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_plate_data" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".45"
        android:text="@string/dummy_date"
        android:textSize="@dimen/anprreading_reading_text_size"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/iv_plate_blacklist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
        android:src="@drawable/blacklist_mark"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/dummy_string" 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/iv_plate_whitelist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
        android:src="@drawable/whitelist_mark"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/dummy_string" 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/ib_plate_detail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
        android:src="@drawable/btn_right_rect"
        android:contentDescription="@string/dummy_string" 
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:focusable="false" />
</it.helian.infrastructure.FE.ui.widget.CheckableLinearLayout>
```

InertCheckBox:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

/**
 * CheckBox that does not react to any user event in order to let the container handle them.
 */
public class InertCheckBox extends CheckBox {

    // Provide the same constructors as the superclass
    public InertCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    // Provide the same constructors as the superclass
    public InertCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    // Provide the same constructors as the superclass
    public InertCheckBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Make the checkbox not respond to any user event
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Make the checkbox not respond to any user event
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int repeatCount, KeyEvent event) {
        // Make the checkbox not respond to any user event
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Make the checkbox not respond to any user event
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyShortcut(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Make the checkbox not respond to any user event
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Make the checkbox not respond to any user event
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Make the checkbox not respond to any user event
        return false;
    }
}
```

CheckableLinearLayout:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * Extension of a linear layout to provide a checkable behaviour
 * 
 * @author marvinlabs
 */
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {

    /**
     * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the checked state of a CheckableRelativeLayout changed.
     */
    public static interface OnCheckedChangeListener {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CheckableLinearLayout layout, boolean isChecked);
    }

    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialise(attrs);
    }

    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, int checkableId) {
        super(context);
        initialise(null);
    }

    /*
     * @see android.widget.Checkable#isChecked()
     */
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    /*
     * @see android.widget.Checkable#setChecked(boolean)
     */
    public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
        for (Checkable c : checkableViews) {
            c.setChecked(isChecked);
        }

        if (onCheckedChangeListener != null) {
            onCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged(this, isChecked);
        }
    }

    /*
     * @see android.widget.Checkable#toggle()
     */
    public void toggle() {
        this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
        for (Checkable c : checkableViews) {
            c.toggle();
        }
    }

    public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener) {
        this.onCheckedChangeListener = onCheckedChangeListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        final int childCount = this.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
            findCheckableChildren(this.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read the custom XML attributes
     */
    private void initialise(AttributeSet attrs) {
        this.isChecked = false;
        this.checkableViews = new ArrayList<Checkable>(5);
    }

    /**
     * Add to our checkable list all the children of the view that implement the interface Checkable
     */
    private void findCheckableChildren(View v) {
        if (v instanceof Checkable) {
            this.checkableViews.add((Checkable) v);
        }

        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            final int childCount = vg.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
                findCheckableChildren(vg.getChildAt(i));
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isChecked;
    private List<Checkable> checkableViews;
    private OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener;
}
```

### Links

[InertCheckBox](https://github.com/marvinlabs/android-tutorials-custom-selectable-listview/blob/master/src/fr/marvinlabs/widget/InertCheckBox.java)

[CheckableLinearLayout](http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/29/custom-listview-ability-check-items/)

Comment: So the whole row is a checkbox?

Comment: Hmmmm... now i see `< stuff />`. Then what is your checkbox exactly? You didn't give the checkbox its own on click listener?

Comment: I have updated the adater layout with all the real items. Well when I set android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" autonatically the row is checked when I click any point of the row itself. I just would like to prevent this

Comment: Why are you setting it to multiple choice?

Comment: Because my application needs to handle multiple selection. But making the row be selected only when clicking on the row checkbox is more elegant.

Comment: That is no reason att all. Why wont your own checkbox be enough? They can be checked individually.

Comment: Can you please answer me and show me your solution? Sorry but I don't get it without an example

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand the problem. I suggested to remove the `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"` from your .xml. And then tell me what does not work. In my opinion you can do without as you have your individual checkboxes already. Please try and report.

Comment: So you are saying to: 1 remove multipleChoice 2 loop over the entire row and look for the checked state of the relative row checkbox. This way I get the selected listview row anyway. Am I right ?

Comment: In that way you get ALL selected rows. `loop over the entire row`? You mean all rows?

Comment: yes... I want to retrieve all the selected rows. About your answer yes i mean all rows. I am testing your solution at the moment. I think this is easier than I though...